# Add delta into tablix SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

This is type of my dataset:

```
| Date(dd/mm/yyyy) | Value |
|------------------|-------|
| 01.01.2018       | 50    |
| 01.01.2019       | 100   |
| 01.03.2019       | 200   |
| 01.05.2019       | 400   |
```

from this dataset i maked tablix:

```
| Date  | 01.01.2018|01.01.2019 | 01.03.2019 | 01.05.2019 |    Δ  |
|-------|-----------|-----------|------------|------------|-------|
| Value |50         |100        | 200        | 400        |300    |
```

**How to put into tablix change value(+300) between 2 dates: 01.05.2019 -01.01.2019?**

I used construction with `lookup` function, but it doesn't work:

1. made dataset with 2 dates:01.05.2019 and 01.01.2019
2. `=lookup(min(Fields!Date.Value,"dataset2"), Fields!Date.Value, Fields!Value.Value, "dataset1")`

Comment: If your dataset if ordered by date and you always want the first and last values then just use `=Last(Fields!Value.Value) - First(Fields!Value.Value)`

Comment: the max value is the last, but minimun doesn't. The first value in 2019 year

Answer (score 0):

If you add a **parent** column group call for example `colgrpYear` and set the grouping expression to be something like:

```
=YEAR(Fields!Date.Value)
```

This will group by the year -- you can hide the column group header if you like.

Then set the calculation expression to ..

```
=Last(Fields!Value.Value, "colgrpYear") - First(Fields!Value.Value, "colgrpYear")
```

This will scope the expression within the just the year that the cell resides in.

**Note** The scope must be in double quotes and is case sensitive.

Comment: thx, i do that u say, but i have mistake: `Expression Value for textbox have a parameter , which cant be used for aggregate function. Value of parameter need to be sting constant...`

Comment: Can you post an image of your report design including the row groups panel and highlight where yiu are using the expression and l will take a look later